# Why does Erlang's random number generation seeding require 3 integers?

Tags: random, erlang

Erlang's [`rand:seed/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html#seed-2) uses 3 integers to seed the RNG.

Whereas RNG implementations commonly require 1 integer for a seed, why does Erlang's use 3 specifically?

Answer (score 1):

[Erlang uses a variant of the Wichmann-Hill algorithm](http://erlang.org/doc/man/random.html) as its PRNG.  This [algorithm dates to 1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichmann%E2%80%93Hill), when 16 bit processors were common.  To achieve a reasonably long cycle (for the time), it pools the results of three different linear congruential generators (LCGs), each of which had a cycle length < 2<sup>15</sup>.  The pooled result has a combined cycle length of

Each of the LCGs has its own integer state, so three separate seed values are required.

Comment: This is for the old `random` module, whereas the new [`rand`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rand.html) module uses [xoroshiro116+ and xorshift1024*](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/). Maybe the 3 seeds were just kept as a holdover from the old module?

Comment: Glad to hear that it has switched, Wichmann-Hill is not that great compared to modern PRNGs.  Not being an Erlang programmer myself, I went with what the linked documentation showed.  It sounds plausible that they stuck with 3 seeds for backwards compatibility.